# Non-normal distribution for index variabels in 1 Latent Profile

Tags: profile

I've ran a latent profile with 8 index variables and settled on a four profile solution. But when looking at the distributions of the index variables within each profile, one of my profile's has non-normal distributions for all 8 index variables.

Does this indicate that the profile is 'inaccurate'?